# Jar-архив и исполняемый файл

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня в архиве jar лежит `main class` и исполняемый файл exe. Как из main класса запустить этот исполняемый файл?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] cmd = { "C:\\path\\test.exe" };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```